# Android: json's value is null

Tags: java, android, json

In my Android project, when a user logs in, it connects to our server and delivers JSON data to the client. If incorrect username or password is provided, the server responds with JSON data structured as follows:

```
{
    "d": {
        "__type": "FMService.LoginUser:#StarHope.FMS.Web.Pages.Service",
        "Error": "wrong",
        "Permissions": null,
        "UserInfo": null
    }
}
```

However, when the user inputs the correct username and password, the value returned from the "Error" key is null. Is this code the correct way to handle this?

```
try
{
    //when Error is not null
    String error = (String) map.get("Error");   
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
    //when Error is null
}
```

Comment: also add json when  user enter the right username and password here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse your json string as use `isNull` to check if `jsonobject` content NULL or not before adding value to Map:

```
JSONObject jobject=new JSONObject("YOUR_JSON_STRING");


if(!jobject.isNull("d")){
  JSONObject jobjd=jobject.getJSONObject("d");
 String strtype,strError;
  if(jobjd.isNull("__type")){
     strtype=jobjd.getString("__type");
    }
   else{
      //do some code here
        strtype="is null";
    }
  if(jobjd.isNull("Error")){
     strError=jobjd.getString("Error");
    }
   else{
      //do some code here
        strError="is null";
    }
    //.....same code here for Permissions and UserInfo
}

else{
   //do some code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29). This method will raise a `JSONException` if the mapping is missing.

> public String getString (String name)
>
> Added in API level 1 Returns the value mapped by name if it exists,
>   coercing it if necessary.
>
> Throws JSONException  if no such mapping exists.

You can also test if the mapping exists or is null using [`isNull()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull%28java.lang.String%29)

Note that the `Error` field is inside the `d` object, not the root.